# The limit of an expression

Tags: limits

I would like to know what's the limit of the following expression
$$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0}\alpha^{-3}e^{-\frac{1}{2\alpha^2}}.$$

Comment: put $\beta=\frac{1}{\alpha}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIMIT AT $0^+$.

taking logarithm after putting

$$\beta=\frac{1}{\alpha}$$

with $\beta \to +\infty$,

we get

$$(\beta)^2(\frac{3log(\beta)}{\beta^2}-\frac{1}{2})$$

and your limit is $0$.

we used that

$\lim_{\beta\to +\infty}\frac{log(\beta)}{\beta}=0$.

At $0^-$, by the same way, we find $0$.